# Can I access my repository created using visualsvn in another system?

Tags: php, svn, repository, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to use TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN Server to use version control.

I installed VisualSVN Server in my system and created a repository in the server. I created two users (one for me and one for my friend). How can I access this repository to use in my friend's TortoiseSVN? I tried to use the repository URL which I got from the VisualSVN Server, but it says there is no such host.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add suggested hostname into `hosts` on target system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is about basic networking, in fact. Not really related to TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN Server.

Make sure that your friend has access to your LAN where VisualSVN Server is installed and server's port is properly forwarded from the router to the server machine (do you have a fixed IP?). As well, you may need to adjust firewall and proxy settings if you use any.